# Group files based on given months

Tags: python

I have a given s3 folder which contains multiple parquet files. Files have specific format as e.g. `GROUP_ACCOUNT_USD_20201103.parquet`. S2 folder can have multiple files with different months.

What is needed is to group these files based on the date in the file name. Grouping is parameterized, say if, month is given as 2, then there will be 6 groups created of 2 months each and all files will be placed in their respective groups depending on the date in the filename string.

I have already created a dictionary containing key as month number and its list containing files falling in that key.

The logic goes like this:

```
for keys, values in groupby(filelist, key=group_func):
    for element in group:
        append_value(dict,key,element)
```

The grouping function is defined as

```
def grouping_func(args):
    file = args['Key']
    val = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1]
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(val,'%Y%m%d').strftime('%m')
```

Append function:

```
def append_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    if key in dict_obj:
        dict_obj[key].append(value) 
    else:
        dict_obj[key] = []
        dict_obj[key].append(value)
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to group by 2 months, it is not grouping is correctly. I tried with `relativedelta(months=2)`.

And changed my grouping function to

```
def grouping_func(args):
    file = args['Key']
    val = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1] 
    m =  datetime.datetime.strptime(val,'%Y%m%d')  
    m = m + relativedelta(months=2)  
    return m.strftime('%m')
```

I guess the problem is with the `grouping_func`.

The grouping function needs to be generic to cater for any number of months or days or week or year.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are not splitting the string correctly

```
val = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1]
```

should be

```
val = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
```

also you should use `splitext` in case the `.` does not exist when separating file names.

Secondly you can do not need the relative delta. You can create a dict which contains all the filenames categorized by month and then group the dictionary keys according to your timeframe.

```
# categorize files to dictionary per month
def categorize_files(filelist):
    file_dict = {}
    for file in filelist:
        val = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1] 
        m =  datetime.datetime.strptime(val,'%Y%m%d')  
        file_dict.setdefault(m.month, []).append(file)
    return file_dict

# group file dictionary according to your desired time frame
def group_by_months(file_dict, months):
    group_dict = {}
    #place if to check if months is >0 and <=12
    groups = [k for k in range(months, 13, months)]
    sorted_keys = sorted(file_dict.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
       for gr in groups:
           if int(key) <= gr:
               group_dict.setdefault(str(gr), []).extend(file_dict[key])
               break
    return group_dict

file_dict = categorize_files(filelist)
month_dict = group_by_months(file_dict, 2) # group by 2 months
```

Comment: thanks @JimS. in your function group_by_months, line group_dict[str(gr)] = month_dict[key]
is erroring out. what it would be there ? Thanks

Comment: yes i typed a wrong variable name, should be okay now

Comment: I ran this @JimS, month_dict giving me None, while the file_dict is showing the correct results.

Comment: Thanks @JimS, I used return group_dict at the end of method group_by_months , isnt giving the desired results in case when i pass months = 2

Comment: i was missing the return statement

Comment: In total there are 23 files in the folder :- 17 files from Nov, 3 files from Dec, 2 from Jan and 1 from Feb. These files are correctly grouped when i use method categorize_files. When i pass in months = 2 in group_by_months , its returning 1 file from Feb and 3 from Dec. Thanks @JimS

Comment: i corrected it, the problem was that it replaced the list instead of appending to it